# How to pull through custom post type by custom taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've made a custom post type type called "Videos" and within that post type a custom category called "Crystal" while using this plugin(https://wordpress.org/plugins/video-thumbnails/ to generate the YouTube videos thumbnail into the post.

I'm trying to pull through all of the Crystal posts and only display the video thumbnail on the page with a permalink to the post.

Here is my code;

```
<div class="block" id="home-three">
    <p>YouTube</p>

        <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type'         => 'videos',
                'post_status'       => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'orderby'           => 'date',
                'order'             => 'DESC',
                'post_parent'       => 0,
                'tax_query'         => 'crystal',
            );

            $count = 1;
        ?>  
        <?php $video_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

            <?php while ( $video_query->have_posts() ) : $video_query->the_post(); ?>

                <div>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php if( ( $video_thumbnail = get_video_thumbnail() ) != null ) { echo "<img src='https://wordpress.org/plugins/video-thumbnails/" . $video_thumbnail . "' />"; } ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters), the `tax_query` parameters accepts an array.

So your `WP_Query` arguments should be:

```
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'videos',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
            'orderby'           => 'date',
            'order'             => 'DESC',
            'post_parent'       => 0,
            'tax_query'         => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => 'crystal'
                )
            )
        );
    ?>
```

You could also use the [Category Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters):

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'videos',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'post_parent'       => 0,
        'category_name'     => 'crystal'
    );
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I get this error now

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/ashleydance/public_html/wp-content/themes/ashleydance/templates/page-home.php on line 65

Comment: You gotta post more code. I don't know what's on line 65 of your page-home.php

Comment: you are missing an `endwhile`

Comment: i've added an endwhile an no there is no error, only problem is the custom post type is not being pulled through at all, any ideas? http://pastebin.com/ZiWh91Y2

Comment: First I would remove the `tax_query` params and see if you get back all the `videos` posts. If that works, then check your `tax_query` -- `taxonomy`. I assumed it was `category` because you said it was a category in your original post. Maybe it's called something else?